# Retrieving a specific value from mysql database based on parameters

Tags: java, mysql, database

I want to retrieve a users name from the username and password that they have entered into textfields. i want to pass these values as parameter to method which will then identify the users name for printout. please help. something like this...

```
 public void getUser(String username, String password)throws SQLException{
 String qry = "SELECT UserName From USER....";

   Connection con = null;
   PreparedStatement stmt = null;

   try{

con = DriverManager.getConnection("URL");
stmt = con.prepareStatement(qry);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Your method signature and your intention are completely contradicting each other.

Comment: username is already in text field why u want it?

Answer (score 0):

If not is an update or an insert, don't use executeUpdate()

You must use executeQuery().

Try this:

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
String qry = "SELECT UserName From USER where username=? and password=?";
   try{

         con = DriverManager.getConnection("URL");
         stmt = con.prepareStatement(qry);
         stmt.setString(1, username);
         stmt.setString(2, password);
         rs =  stmt.executeQuery();
         while (rs.next()) {
               System.out.println(rs.getString("UserName"));
         }
        ...
```

Regards

Comment: Can be with an if, but the table can be more one row, depend of values into database (same user and password, but differents roles)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to get the user's full name from db and your table structure is something like this:

`fullname | username | password`

you could do the following:

```
Connection c = null;
PreparedStatement s = null;
try {
  c = DriverManager.getConnection("URL");
  s = c.prepareStatement("SELECT fullname FROM user WHERE username=? and password=?");
  s.setString(1, username);
  s.setString(2, password);

  ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery();
  if(rs.next()) 
    return rs.getString("fullname");

  return null; // no user found!
} catch(SQLException e) {
  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
} finally {
   // close s and c
}
```

Note: This assumes that the password that is passed to the method is in the same "form" as it is stored in db (i.e. either plain text or hashed (+salted))

Comment: return rs.getString("fullname");  <<<GIVES ERROR EVEN IF I CHANGE "fullname" to what my database reflects

Comment: This is because your method has `void` return type. Either change it to return string or process the name in the method directly!

Comment: it still requires a return statement? is this after finally block?

Comment: will it print "UserRole" or the value contained in the UserRole as in database

Comment: your method is declared to return nothing. so just remove the return statements from my answer. It all depends on how you want to process the values from your DB. To get the user role change the select statement to `SELECT userrole ...` and then fetch it with `rs.getString("userrole")` (You can even fetch both values at once!)

Comment: sorry one more question, when clicked on Login in a GUI, i want it to display UserRole in another GUI. the method that generates UserRole is in Login Form, but i want it to display in Another GUI FORM. how do i pass this? :(

Comment: you better ask this in a new question and post some code of your GUI elements.

Comment: the label is private in another GUI.
if(rs.next()) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password are correct ");
               userrole = model.findUserRole(txtUsername.getText(), txtPassword.getText());
               MainMenu menu = new MainMenu();
               
        menu.userRoleLabel.setText(userrole);
               menu.setVisible(true);
               LoginForm l = new LoginForm();
               l.setVisible(false);

Comment: please post this in a new question with more details... seriously!

Answer (score 0):

try this its very simple example

```
 private boolean validate_login(String id,String password) {

try{           
   Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");  // MySQL database connection
   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:studentdb.sqlite");     
   PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from student_table where id=? and password=?");
   pst.setString(1, id); 
   pst.setString(2, password);
   ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();                        
   if(rs.next())            
       return true;    
   else
       return false;


try{           
   Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");  // MySQL database connection
   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:studentdb.sqlite");     
   PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from student_table where id=? and password=?");
   pst.setString(1, id); 
   pst.setString(2, password);
   ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();                        
   if(rs.next())            
       return true;    
   else
       return false;  
  }
  catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
   return false;
  }       
 }
```